# Getting 'ngModule' not found error while running jest

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am unable to run test cases on my system, every time I try to run it throws an error

It is not a circular dependency error as it compiles perfectly

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngModule' of undefined
at isModuleWithProviders (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:538:38)
      at expandModuleWithProviders (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:531:7)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Function.get (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:124:29)
      at getNgModuleDef (../../../packages/core/src/render3/definition.ts:756:27)
      at isNgModule (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:542:12)
      at transitiveScopesFor (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:443:8)
      at setScopeOnDeclaredComponents (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:394:28)
      at Object.flushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible [as ɵflushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible] (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:59:11)
      at TestBedRender3.Object.<anonymous>.TestBedRender3.checkGlobalCompilationFinished (../../../packages/core/testing/src/r3_test_bed.ts:408:7)
      at TestBedRender3.Object.<anonymous>.TestBedRender3.resetTestingModule (../../../packages/core/testing/src/r3_test_bed.ts:237:10)
      at Function.Object.<anonymous>.TestBedRender3.resetTestingModule (../../../packages/core/testing/src/r3_test_bed.ts:186:26)
      at ../../../packages/core/testing/src/before_each.ts:25:13
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:386:30)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:117:43)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:385:36)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:143:47)
```

However, it seems to work fine on very other system. I have mapped angular,npm and node versions and they are same in every system so is the code. Still m facing this issue and have tried almost everything like:

- Upgrading/downgrading angular versions
- Deleting & Re-installing node_modules
- Using different angular versions
- Removing global angular if any
- Check `isModuleWithProvider` function too and its set for the edge case for checking undefined

Current versions:

1. Node: 14.17.3
2. Angular CLI: 10.1.4
3. Node: 14.17.3
4. OS: darwin x64
5. jest: 26.6.3

Any advice..??